# Is there a way to set AVD Default Language when creating on command line?

Tags: android, android-emulator, iso, android-testing

I setup a couple of robotium tests and stuff for our CI. 
Everthing works fine so far. I just cant figure out how i can define the **Default Language** for the AVD i creating.

I read [Managing AVD](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html#DefaultLocation) but there is no option listed for this.

How you do this when your Robotium Tests also make use of the "searchText" feature, but fail because the emulator runs on different language ?

Using the android avd command also don't show any option for that. I had a quick look in the config files for for AVDs created and there also is no language setting.

Comment: I tired an different approach using Android Emulator Plugin. The Plugin creates an AVD with an locale on the fly. But the Maven Android Plugin reports it cant find any emulator. Strange!

Comment: When the AVD gets created by Jenkins there is an Bug report which seem to doom this aproach: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12821

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to switch the language after the emulator was started:

`adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.intent.action.SET_LOCALE --es com.android.intent.extra.LOCALE EN`

[source](http://qathread.blogspot.co.il/2017/01/preparing-android-emulator-for-test.html%20*source*)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set Android emulator default language on starting command using -change-locale:

```
emulator -avd <avd-name> -change-locale fr-CA
```

Relase note - https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/09/emulator-29112-stable.html

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working on images v21, but works on image with android v31 